# vscode ignores partially noImplicitAny

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nest

I have a Nestjs Typescript project
my tsconfig.json is as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }
}
```

when i compile using `nest build` I get several

> Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

for example this method

```
async findAll() {
  const result = await this.prismaService.partnership_certificate.findMany();
  return result.map((item) => new PartnershipCertificate(item));
}
```

the issue is that vscode doesn't mark that method with an error as the compiler does

I noticed that when trying this statement (as suggested in one of the answers on SO)

```
const func = (test) => alert(test);
```

vscode does produce the correct error (about the 'any' type)
I'm not sure what's the difference between this statement and the above method but they both produce the error, according to the compilation output

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the first statment the IDE is smart enough to specifie a type for `item` because you are maping an array of `PartnershipCertificate & {_id: Types.ObjectId;}` so it does not show any error

but in the second statement, it does not have any information with wich it can guess `item` type so the error is obvious